# Limiting the amount of guests on a Hyper-V host

Tags: hyper-v, scvmm

Is anyone aware of a way to limit the number of hosts allowed on single Hyper-V host? Either by quantity or resource usage?

We are planning on using SCVMM and MS Lab Manager for a development lab setup. This is for testing a distributed application that requires lots of worker nodes. These worker nodes are likely to be (pretty high spec) workstations, so I am trying to avoid some one using the lab management console to deploy an environment and overloading these nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using SCVMM you can most definitely do this.  First create a template or two with the specs that you want.  Save these templates in your SCVMM library.  Now, from within SCVMM create a group and add your users who will be managing/creating vm's.  You can now assign a quota for this group, or by user.  Now it's just some simple math.  How many VMs can you put on there before it's overloaded?  Set that as your quota and you should be all set.  This will allow the group/users to spin up individual VMs of that size until they reach their quota limit.

Comment: If I have 2 hosts, and I assign a quote of 2 VM's, is there anything to stop it trying to spin up 2 VM's on one host, rather than 1 per host?

Comment: They would be able to spin up 2 VMs total (assuming the quota is 2) per Cluster.  # of nodes is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

no official builtin way but you could create a scheduled event to reset the max cpu utilization to some preset number.

not even sure if scvmm 2012 has this capability but if it does you can download the RC for it to find out.